# 2D lighting with HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, lighting

I am making a recreation of Terraria, a 2D voxel game, that requires lighting.

What I want, is to input an array of light objects, including x y location, intensity, et cetera, and get an HTML canvas of transparent circles that gradually fade out. Here is my current implementation of this:

```js
const lights = [{
    x: 30,
    y: 30,
    color: "#f8f8f8",

    fade: 10,
    intensity: 5,
  },
  {
    x: 60,
    y: 40,
    color: "#f8f8f8",

    fade: 10,
    intensity: 5,
  },
  {
    x: 65,
    y: 80,
    color: "#ffffff",

    fade: 12,
    intensity: 6,
  },
];

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const fadeMultiplier = 2;

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.lineWidth = 2;

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
for (const light of lights) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = light.color;
  ctx.fillStyle = light.color;
  ctx.lineWidth = fadeMultiplier * 2;

  const {
    fade,
    intensity
  } = light;

  for (let i = 0; i < fade; i++) {
    const circleWidth = intensity + (fade - i) * fadeMultiplier;
    if (circleWidth > 0) {
      ctx.globalAlpha = i / fade;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.ellipse(light.x, light.y, circleWidth, circleWidth, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.ellipse(light.x, light.y, intensity, intensity, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

This works by first drawing a black rectangle to fill the canvas. After, it then draws partially transparent circles, gradually getting smaller in radius and transparency, for each light object.

I will then draw that over everything on the canvas, producing a lighting effect. The problem is that the white color you are seeing on the image needs to be transparent. Right now it is just a solid white, which would cover the screen.

What can I do to upgrade my current function to create a light effect like I have described? Or should I try an entirely different approach? My main goal is performance, if I can get it to under 3ms, I'll be happy.

Comment: Looks good, but what you _should_ do seems to depend entirely on context we don't have for the game you're making. For example, if you can draw everything (characters, walls etc) on top of these lights (is this a top-down game?), then you're fine. If not, then what are your design constraints to work with?

Comment: The answer to this question is entirely based on the type of lighting that OP would like. The HTML canvas element has all the tools you need to handle 2D lighting in any way you'd like using JavaScript, but the technique and methods will differ depending on your end goal.

Comment: @OOPSStudio I have provided an example of my end goal in my question.

Comment: Is the issue that when you paste many circles over each other they become more and more opaque? And you would rather a different effect?

Comment: @OOPSStudio Yes, that is correct.